# jq update list elements based on values

Tags: json, jq

Is it possible to use `jq` to turn the following JSON data

```
[
    {
        "a": null,
        "b": [
            {
                "c": "cc",
                "d": "dd1"
            },
            {
                "c": "cc",
                "d": "dd1",
                "e": "ee",
                "f": "ff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "b": [
            {
                "c": "cc",
                "d": "dd2",
                "e": "ee",
                "f": "ff"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

into

```
[
    {
        "a": null,
        "b": [
            [
                "cc", "d1"
            ],
            [
                "cc", "d1", "ff"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "b": [
            [
                "cc", "d2", "ff"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

?

Note that the purpose is to reduce the `b` list with certain elements of its items based on a condition. The condition assigns the string `d1` if the value of `d` is `dd1`, otherwise `d2` is assigned if `dd2` is present.

The following unsuccessful attempt demonstrates the idea:

```
$ jq -r '.[].b[] = [.[].b[].c, ?, .[].b[].f?]'
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @oguzismail See the updated question. I am unaware how to address the conditional part and how to update each element individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the best way to do what you want, but it does get the desired output and it has the conditional you asked about.

```
jq '.[].b |= map(
   [ .c,
     (if .d == "dd1" then "d1" elif .d == "dd2" then "d2" else . end),
     .f // empty
   ] )'
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. This sort of if-then-else logic is indeed what was needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the value of the `d` key, you would use this jq filter:

```
jq '.[].b[]|=(to_entries|map(.value))' file
```

That updates the `b` array into all values of the inner objects.

If you want to update the `d`, you could use this filter:

```
jq '.[].b[] |= (to_entries|
                  map(
                    if(.key=="d") then 
                       .value|=sub("d+";"d") 
                    else . 
                    end
                    |.value)
                )' file
```

that adds a check if the key is `d` the associated value is updated to remove the duplicated `d` character from the string. This requires jq to support for regex (to be able to use the `sub` function).